# JS errors when loading Polymer Project starter toolbox set-up

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-1.x, polymer-serve

*From Polymer Slack Group: @drjosh9000 posted:*

I get a JS console full of errors when trying out https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up. How can I eliminate them and get the page to load properly?

[image]

### Edit

#### Note:

The following does ***not*** work:

```
polymer serve --open
```

The following ***does*** work:

```
polymer build
polymer serve build/bundled
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you finish running `bower install` command? Polymer CLI does it for you automatically but have you stopped at one point?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed `bower install` as `polymer.js` is missing and causing other functions to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think Polymer package is missing. Try this:

```
open cmd
cd my-project # where my-project is the root directory of your project
bower install --save polymer/polymer
```